# How to stop a background image centring at a specific width

Tags: css

Is there a way to stop a background image centering at a specific width?

To illustrate the problem, reduce the width of the following site untill scroll bars appear. Then observe how the background image remains centred, however, all other elements hold their place.

See it [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2306276/site/front.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add min-width to your #header css

```
#header { background: #f8f8f8 url("background.jpg") no-repeat center bottom; background-position-y: 160px; min-width:960px;}
```

Comment: Thanks! couldn't see the wood for the trees.

Answer (score 1):

Use media queries to set some styles at a specific width and use `background-position` to stop centering the image. An example: http://3.jsbin.com/ojemur/4/watch (resize your browser window and if the background gets red the image doesn't center vertically)

More information about media queries:

- [css3 media queries on webdesignerwall](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries)
- [Responsive design with CSS3 media queries on webdesignerwall](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries)
- [A crash course in CSS media queries on nettuts+](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-a-crash-course-in-css-media-queries/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Wouter, can you give me an example please?

Comment: @pingu I have added an example